# Equidispersion Property - Why and Where

Tags: self-study, generalized-linear-model, count-data

I've often looked at count data models over the years. And like a lot of statistical models, they can be used/abused in cookbook style.

- Identify equidispersion -> do X model (Poisson).
- Identify overdispersion -> do Y model (some modified Poisson or alternative spec).

However, when I read textbooks on count data models, there is never a non-technical/intuitive explanation of equidispersion.

Instead, to caricature textbooks, you often see: "Equidispersion is mean/variance equality, but variance is often not equal to the mean. The End"

In contrast, my questions on equidispersion are as follows:

- Why would we ever expect the equidispersion property in count data?
- When would we expect to see the equidispersion property as a real life example?
- Is equidispersion interchangable with equiprobable. Therefore, it is equally likely that an event will occur over all counts (say Mon-Sun)?
- And could someone provide the mechanics of how this plays out in a numerical example with count data?

All help would be appreciated.